# How to create apps in different platforms, each of different functionalities with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, cross-platform, flutter-web, user-experience

I was thinking about creating a small project using **Flutter** to create a mobile application along with website accessibility. I am quite new to Flutter and wanted to learn more about it. So basically, my application consists of two user targets; *teachers* and *students*. I want to allow *teachers* to be able to create courses **ONLY** on the website, but *students* and *teachers* are allowed to access the mobile application. *Teachers* can view courses and *students* can join classes through the app. The reason for only allowing *students* in the mobile app is that I want to make use of the gyroscope of mobile phones.

Hence, there are some questions that I need help with:

1. Should I create 2 apps; an independent Flutter Web and an independent mobile app, or pack them together in one app?
2. If I pack them together, how do I make the above conditions possible? I was thinking about checking the device used and displaying different interfaces on different devices. Is this possible?

Also, I am willing to receive any advice on what is better to implement, or what I could change. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can handle this scenario with a single codebase
2. To check if user is using web you can use below condition. You can also use a combination of LayoutBuilder and MediaQuery to show
   responsive UI based on device dimensions.

There are different scenarios which u need to consider while deciding if you should have separate projects.For e.g. If the functionality on the web is completely different, then you can think about 2 app approach.

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

if (kIsWeb) {
  // running on the web!
} else {
  // NOT running on the web! You can check for additional platforms here.
}
```